# Prevent popen() from displaying error on stderr

Tags: c, popen, stderr

I have the following code to find the release of the Linux distribution that I am using.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{

    return print_osinfo();
}

int print_osinfo()
{
    FILE *fp;
    extern FILE* popen();
    char buffer[128];
    int index = 0;

    memset(buffer,0,sizeof(buffer));
    fp = popen("/etc/centos-release", "r");
    if(!fp)
    {
        pclose(fp);
        fp = popen("/etc/redhat-release", "r");
        if(!fp)
        {
            pclose(fp);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp)!= NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n",buffer);
    }
    pclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

If I run the above code on Ubuntu 14.04 I get the following error.

```
sh: 1: /etc/centos-release: not found
```

I fail to understand why it is not trying to open `redhat-release` and then return -1. Also, is there a way to prevent the above error from being displayed on the screen?

Comment: Perhaps by redirecting `stderr` like this `popen("/etc/centos-release 2>/dev/null", "r")`? Or maybe `popen("/etc/centos-release 2>&1", "r");` `stderr` redirected to `stdout`

Comment: Neither /etc/centos-release nor /etc/redhat-release are executable files, so you don't need to use popen/pclose to read them - just use fopen/fclose. Use popen/pclose to run something like "uname -a", which does emit some text info about the current system.

Comment: The errors are not being written to stdout as the title of your question indicates.  They are being written to stderr.

Answer (score 5):

`popen` is a function more suited for accessing the output of a subprocess than for simply accessing the contents of a file. For that, you should use `fopen`. `fopen` takes a file path and a mode as arguments, so all you would need to do is replace your `popen`s with `fopen`s and it should work perfectly.

If you really want to use `popen`, it takes a shell command as it's first argument, not a filename. Try `popen("cat /etc/centos-release","r");` instead.

Now, you might be a bit confused, because both of these functions return a `FILE` pointer. `fopen` returns a pointer to the file you passed as an argument. `popen`, however, returns a pipe pointing to the output of the command you passed to it, which C sees as a `FILE` pointer. This is because, in C, all i/o is file access; C's only connection to the outside world is through files. So, in order to pass the output of some shell command, `popen` creates what C sees as a `FILE` in memory, containing the output of said shell command. Since it is rather absurd to run a whole other program (the shell command) just to do what `fopen` does perfectly well, it makes far more sense to just use `fopen` to read from files that already exist on disk.

Comment: Why not just `fp = fopen("/etc/centos-release", "r")` (and subsequently `fclose(fp)`)?  There's no obvious reason to use a shell and `cat` when you're just trying to read a file.  And `fopen()` doesn't write to `stderr`, which fixes the error message problem.

Comment: The question was about using `popen()`. I completely agree that `fopen()` is the better choice here, but I wanted to explain why it didn't work, not just a different way to do it.

Comment: Yes, but the question was also about executing the file, which isn't executable.  You could reasonably suggest the best solution (`fopen()`, `fclose()`) and then comment about "if you must use `popen()` then …".  Not pointing out most of the errors of their ways isn't as helpful as doing so.  Also the title is about stopping the errors appearing on standard error; your solution hasn't done that for when the file is `/etc/redhat-release`; the `cat /etc/centos-release` will generate the error still.

Comment: Fair enough. Point taken